# Thunderbird, chat extension, what about notification

Tags: linux, thunderbird, notifications, chat, kde-4

As you may have noticed, Thunderbird's new version has now a built-in feature that allows you to use it as a chat client. For example, Google talk. So I initiated my own account. The problem is that there are no notifications, for example in the tray. Any ideas?

Comment: peraueb1989: If you submitted [an edit to this question](http://superuser.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/27868), I rejected it since it wasn't apparently from you. Make sure you're logged in before editing. If not, feel free to ignore this comment (or better yet, let me know, so I can delete it).

Comment: Notification works in the windows version. There's a ding.

Comment: Daniel, I tried no edits. :)

Answer (score 3):

[**FiltaQuilla**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) is an add-on that enables the user to properly and precisely configure notifications, based on built-in filters or enhanced filters. Maybe one could try to extend its functionality to filter/notify chat messages. I don't have a full answer here, but it might be a good start. I would not be surprised if the developer of this add-on would make something for chat.

Comment: In Linux the notification system has some lacks :(

Answer (score 1):

This I currently use [this extension](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742746#c4) to deal with this issue.

Comment: Hey Beercow, thanks for contributing. Note that on Superuser it's considered good form to explain why something is helpful, not just link it. Moo!